# electron-builder MSI installer asar file too large

Tags: angular, npm, electron, electron-builder, asar

I have an Angular app for which I need to create an MSI installer. I have successfully created an electron app (`npm run electron`), but when I try to create the installer I get this error:

> error LGHT0263 : 'C:...\release\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar' is
> too large, file size must be less than 2147483648.

I ran the commands in this order:

1. `npm run electron` --> to run the electron app itself to see if it works (I closed the app before doing the next steps)
2. `npm run tsc`
3. `npm run step2`
4. `npm run electron:build`

I assume I am including too many files in electron-builder.json, but I am not sure what I can remove and what is required for the app to run since this is my first time using electron and electron-builder.

When I set `"asar": false` in electron-builder.json, the MSI installer is created, but I get the warning `asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended`, it takes forever (i.e. 30-ish minutes) to build and the MSI packet is almost 1.5 GB in size.

**Does anybody know how I can reduce the asar size?**

This is my project structure:

```
|- dist
|- electron
   |- main.ts
   |- package.json
|- node_modules
|- release
|- src
   |- all angular source code
|- angular.json
|- electron-builder.json
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
|- tsconfig.serve.json
```

Scripts in package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "electron": "ng build --configuration electron && electron .",
    "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.serve.json",
    "step2": "ng build --base-href ./ --configuration electron",
    "electron:build": "electron-builder build --publish=never"
  }
```

electron-builder.json:

```json
{"asar": true,
  "directories": {
    "output": "release/"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "from": "dist",
      "filter": ["**/*"]
    },
    {
      "from": "electron",
      "filter": ["**/*"]
    },
    {
      "from": "src",
      "filter": ["**/*"]
    },
    "!**/*.ts",
    "!*.map",
    "!package.json",
    "!package-lock.json",
    "!node_modules/**",
    "!.angular/**",
    "!.vscode/**",
    "!cypress/**",
    "!release/**"
  ],
  "win": {
    "icon": "offline-test.ico",
    "target": [
      "msi"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.serve.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es2016",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "electron/main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866495/electron-builder-app-size-is-too-large), but I think I am excluding the directory where the MSI file is, so I'm not sure what else I can exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Angular, so I won't be able to give you full working configuration, but whatever library is used, usually when packaging for Electron you first want to bundle your files, and then **only pack these files**.

Roughly, you should:

- Bundle your renderer, main and preload (if you have one) files into a single output folder
- Make sure you use a different output folder for bundling and for packaging (to prevent conflicts)
- Tell the builder to package only the bundle output folder
- Add modules that can't be bundled manually (if you have any)

Once you have everything neatly inside your output folder (I gathered that for Angular the default is `dist/[project-name]`), you can then configure `electron-builder` accordingly:

```json
{
  "extraMetadata": {
    // This will change the `main` field of your `package.json`,
    // so electron-builder will use the file made for prod.
    "main": "dist/[project-name]/[path-to-bundled-main-file]"
  },
  "files": [
    "./dist/[project-name]/**/*"
  ]
}
```

For native module that can't be bundled, you can use the [`asarUnpack`](https://www.electron.build/generated/platformspecificbuildoptions#configuration-asarUnpack) option to include them in the package.

Also, if I'm not wrong, Angular CLI uses webpack to bundle, so you will probably need to use the [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) `electron-main` and `electron-preload` to bundle your Electron files so everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My final app.asar file is ~187 Mb

My final .exe file is ~168 Mb

My installer is ~87 Mb

I'm still cleaning stuff, so far I explicitly excluded SRC code (still under development environment, everything in same folders) by setting

```
{
  ...
  "build": {
    "asar": true,
    "files": [
      "!src/**",
      "!.vscode/**"
    ]
   ...
}
```

Check the content of your ASAR file (install 7-Zip and companion plug-in Asar7z), ensure you're not including undesired files