# How to reduce electron apps size

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

My electron application is insanely big on Mac after installation. It's around 1.39GB for no apparent reason, even though it's around 70MB on Windows. I tried to unpack the dmg file to see what makes it so big then found a file called app.asar that takes a large size of the app (1.22GB) and I don't know how to unpack this file.
So my question is,
How to make the application's size much smaller like on windows?
and what does app.asar file contain?

I'm using electron-builder to build the app by the way

Comment: To unpack an asar file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523617/how-to-unpack-an-asar-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your app.
If your app is too heavy, then it might be natural.
If not; try removing unwanted packages in the `node_modules` directory using `npm`.
Try instructions here :

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution

[Make electron app smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310947/make-electron-app-smaller)

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003

You can also unpack the `asar` file using:

```
npx asar extract app.asar destfolder
```

more on that here [How to unpack an .asar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523617/how-to-unpack-an-asar-file)

it basically contains all you code and stuff.

I hope I could help you .

*some stuff added based on others comments*

Comment: Yes I ran this command to unpack the file but it gives an error in the terminal saying "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app.asar'"

Comment: @MahmoudFarargy are you sure your working directory is the same as the directory that `app.asar` is located? you can change the working directory using the `cd` command.

Comment: Yes, when I specified the directory as you said, and ran the command, the file got extracted correctly. Thanks so much!

Comment: And found out the node_modules folder is around 1.10GB which probably what makes the app so big.

Comment: Thanks! And yes node_modules can get really heavy. There are even some memes about that.